# Relationship between $\ell^p$-norm and $L^p$-norm

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

I have to deal with a problem for Real Analysis of Royden and Fitzpatrick. It is Problem 12 from Section 7.2.

> For $1 \le p < \infty$ and a sequence $a = (a_1, a_2,\ldots) \in
> \ell^p$, define $T_a$ to be the function on the interval $[1,\infty)$ that takes the value $a_k$ on $[k,k+1)$, for $k=1,2,\ldots$. Show that $T_a \in L^p[1,\infty)$ and $\|a\|_p = \|T_a\|_p$.

This means I have to show $T_a \in L^p[1,\infty)$ and
$$\int_{[1,\infty)} \Big|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}  a_k \chi_{[k,k+1)}\Big|^p = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |a_k|^p,$$
where $T_a = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k \chi_{[k,k+1)}$ on $[1,\infty)$.

Here is my attempt.

I think I can show it by using Minkowski's inequality.

$$\Big\| \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_k \chi_{[k,k+1)} \Big\|^p_p \le \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \Big\| a_k \chi_{[k,k+1)} \Big\|^p_p \le \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |a_k|^p.$$

Let $n \to \infty$, by Monotone Convergence Theorem, we obtain $\|T_a\|_p \le \|a\|_p < \infty$, which implies $T_a \in L^p$.

But then, I got stuck.

Does anyone have any advice? I really appreciate it.

Comment: The function represented by the series is equal $f(x)=a_k$ for $k\le x< k+1.$ Hence $|f|^p =|a_k|^p $ for $k\le x< k+1.$ In other words $$|f|^p=\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k|^p\chi_{[k,k+1)}$$

Comment: Ah I see, thank you.